# Incorrect orientations on iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, orientation

I want my app to work in all orientations on iPad, support landscape and portrait on iPhone 6 Plus, and portrait only on other devices.

But it doesn't work correctly on iPhone 6/6s Plus. Rotation is weird and view controllers often present themselves in the wrong orientation.

This is what I currently have in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    let height = window?.bounds.height

    if height > 736.0 {
        // iPad
        return .All
    } else if height == 736.0 {
        // 5.5" iPhones
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        // 4.7", 4", 3.5" iPhones
        return .Portrait
    }

}
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches we can use to set appropriate interface orientations. First of all, using hardcoded heights is prone to bugs and Apple strongly discourages that type of device checking. Instead, we'll use trait collections. `UITraitCollection` is API introduced in iOS 8 and it contains info about the device idiom, display scale and size classes. You can access the trait collection on `UIWindow` and `UIViewController` objects.

In our example we will check first if device is an iPad by using `userInterfaceIdiom` property, then we will check the `displayScale` for iPhone 6/6s Plus (which is 3.0).

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if window?.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            // Check for iPad
            return .All
        } else if window?.traitCollection.displayScale == 3.0 {
            // iPhone 6/6s Plus is currently only iPhone with display scale of 3.0
            return [.Portrait, .Landscape]
        } else {
            // Return Portrait for all other devices
            return .Portrait
        }
    }
```

If you want to know more about trait collections and size classes I recommend reading official [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/)